# Can we get the timestamp information with os.listdir in Python (like ls -l)?

Tags: python, windows, python-os

I contact an `SFTP` server and show files based on the modified timestamp.

Currently, it is done using something like:

1. `files = os.listdir(SFTP)`
2. Loop over `files` and get the timestamp using `os.stat`.
3. Sort the final list in Python.

This looping in Step 2 is very costly when the SFTP is on a different server because it has to make a network call from the server to the SFTP for each and every file.

Is there a way to get both the file and modified time using `os.listdir` or a similar API?

I am using a Windows back-end and the SFTP connection usually is done using the [win32wnet.WNetAddConnection2](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/3.1/pywin32/win32wnet__WNetAddConnection2_meth.html) package. A generic solution would be helpful, if not a specific solution should be fine too.

Comment: Can you explain why it would require a roundtrip? How are you sending commands to the server and how do you have the server run them?

Comment: there's a `scandir.walk()` that returns entries instead of names. On windows it saves a lot of time. are you using Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Windows, you've got a lot to gain to use `os.scandir()` (python 3.5+) or the backport `scandir` module: `scandir.scandir()`

That's because on Windows (as opposed to Linux/Unix), `os.listdir()` already performs a file stat behind the scenes but the result is discarded except for the name. Which forces you to perform another `stat` call.

`scandir` returns a list of directory entries, not names. On windows, the size/object type fields are already filled, so when you perform a `stat` on the entry (as shown in the example below), it's at zero cost:

(taken from https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0471/)

```
def get_tree_size(path):
    """Return total size of files in given path and subdirs."""
    total = 0
    for entry in os.scandir(path):
        if entry.is_dir(follow_symlinks=False):
            total += get_tree_size(entry.path)
        else:
            total += entry.stat(follow_symlinks=False).st_size
    return total
```

so just replace your first `os.listdir()` call by `os.scandir()` and you'll have all the information for the same cost as a simple `os.listdir()`

(this is the most interesting on Windows, and a lot less on Linux. I've used it on a slow filesystem on Windows and got a 8x performance gain compared to good old `os.listdir` followed by `os.path.isdir` in my case)

Comment: `scandir` pulls the results in about 2 seconds! Thanks for the recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

You should use special libraries for this, such as [sftp](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.4/api/sftp.html) or [ftplib](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.4/api/sftp.html), they provide specific utils that will be helpful for you.
Also, you can try to call the interesting command on the server.

Answer (score 2):

If youre able to send one line commands to the server, you could do `[os.stat(i) for i in os.listdir()]`

If that doesn't work for you, I suppose you could just do `os.system("ls -l")`

If neither of those work, please do tell me!

Comment: But the `[os.stat(i) for i in os.listdir()]` is pretty much what we are doing right? It is just one-liner for the same stuff. The later one is a subprocess call which I am trying to avoid.

Comment: @Nishant for the first one, if you're sending the first one for the server to execute, I don't understand why you think it would be a roundabout trip. Please explain?

Comment: The server and the SFTP is two different machines usually. This is the reason there is a round trip. Does that make sense? I specifically use `win32wnet.WNetAddConnection2` in the server.

Comment: @Nishant but if you execute the entire line on the server, there is no need to send information back to the client until you have the data you need with the timestamps.

Comment: Yeah but here is not the client-server round trip (that happens just once), but the Server to SFTP round trip that is happening.